# How to refer by name to local variables in calling function?

Tags: php

I have the code below that in the case of function 'test' works as required, while when the work of 'foreach' is factored into a function things stop working as variables go out of scope. Is there a way to maintain them in scope while being able to factor the code as a function?

```
function test()
{
    $a = 'aaa';
    $b = 'bbb';
    $c = 'ccc';
    $A = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    foreach ($A as $_a) $r[$_a] = $$_a;
    var_dump($r);
}

// running test() gives ['a'=>'aaa','b'=>'bbb','c'=>'ccc']

function KV($A)
{
    foreach ($A as $_a) $r[$_a] = $$_a;
    return $r;
}

function test1()
{
    $a = 'aaa';
    $b = 'bbb';
    $c = 'ccc';
    $A = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    $r = KV($A);
    var_dump($r);
}
```

running test1() gives `['a'=>NULL,'b'=>NULL,'c'=>NULL]`
comment: the looping variable has been named '_a' in order to avoid name clashes with possible variable names.

just to understand the usefulness of the need, I write bellow a real case where the function would be used.

```
$r = [
    'series' => $series, 
    'aa' => $aa, 
    'issueDate' => $issueDate, 
    'invoiceType' => $invoiceType, 
    'vatPaymentSuspension' => $vatPaymentSuspension, 
    'currency' => $currency, 
    'exchangeRate' => $exchangeRate,
    ];
if ($correlatedInvoices) {
    $r['correlatedInvoices'] = $correlatedInvoices;
}
if ($selfPricing) {
    $r['selfPricing'] = $selfPricing;
}
```

So at the end the scope is to write instead of the above 10 lines of code the bellow abbreviation of it (explode will be used to convert the string to an array and the '?' would be treated accordingly).

$r=KVextended('series,aa,issueDate,invoiceType,vatPaymentSuspension,currency,exchangeRate,?correlatedInvoices,?selfPricing');

Comment: in general - no, each function is separate scope which does not have access to caller's scope, but you can try to define them as `global`, but this will pollute global namespace

Comment: That's what function arguments are for, passing in data to the function. If you want to change the original variable (defined outside) instead of getting a copy (default), you can [pass it by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: Pass the needed variables into the KV function as arguments.

Comment: The variables of the function where KV is used, are unknown, so I suppose I cannot define them as globals in an easy way.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ You should format your code in a more sensible way to make it readable. Having multiple statements on a single line just makes it unnecessary hard to follow. Good code is easy to read.

Comment: @M.Eriksson The only lines that have more than one statement in one line are: $a='aaa';$b='bbb';$c='ccc'; I could easily write it as: [$a,$b,$c]=['aaa','bbb','ccc']; that would be a single statement but it takes more characters while is not exactly more readable. Regarding the foreach indentation conveys the scope any way.

Comment: That's not the only one. The last code block has a couple of `if`-statements all in one line as well. That together with defining `$r` in the line above in a single row does make it much harder to read. They all add up. Making the code as easy to read as possible is a good thing. There are no bonus points or gains by writing as your code as compact as possible, just drawbacks.

Comment: I still don't understand the usefulness of the need

Comment: Just passing, through. The example you gave makes even less sense for the test you've created. If someone on my team was trying to get this to work I'd just tell to dump the first three variables into an array and use `array_combine`. There is not a clean, or best practice for moving variables around outside of the existing scopes. In the end, you'll find just passing variables you need is easiest and very common. Also, you may be interested in the spread operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give all variables defined to your function with `get_defined_vars()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

```php
function KV($varsToGet,$varsDefined){
  $returnArray = [];
  foreach($varsToGet as $varToGet) 
    if(isset($varsDefined[$varToGet])){
      $returnArray[$varToGet] = $varsDefined[$varToGet];
    }
  return $returnArray;
}

function test1(){
  $a='aaa';
  $b='bbb';
  $c='ccc';
  $A=['a','b','c'];
  $r = KV($A,get_defined_vars());
  print_r($r);
}
```

or

```php
function test1(){
  $a='aaa';
  $b='bbb';
  $c='ccc';
  $A=['a','b','c'];
  $r = array_filter(get_defined_vars(),function($index)use($A){ 
    return in_array($index,$A);
  },ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
  print_r($r);
}
```

Comment: The solution proposed first case of test1, is much cleaner than my hack. I believed that get_defined_vars() was giving all variables globals etc, while in the context of a function it seems it gives only defined vars. In case "get_defined_vars" was able to take an index indicating the level of previous function ( eg 0 current function, 1 calling function etc ) than it could be used inside KV instead of in test1, for now this is the best solution available.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that actually there is no way to do it,so I present the solution I devised to do the same bypassing the lack of options.
By the way I suggest to the language designer to provide a bidimensional array like $LOCALS where we can access values of previous calls as `$LOCALS[-1]['nameOfLocalInCallingFunction']` or something similar ($LOCALS[1])

The solution bellow seems the best option available to obtain the scope at hand:

```
<?php

function test(){
  $a='aaa';$b='bbb';$c='ccc';
  $A=['a','b','c'];
  foreach($A as $_a) $r[$_a]=$$_a;
  var_dump($r);
}

// running test() gives ['a'=>'aaa','b'=>'bbb','c'=>'ccc']

function KV($A){
  foreach($A as $a) 
    $r[]="'$a'=>\$$a";
  return '[' . implode(',',$r) . '];' ;
}

function test1(){
  $a='aaa';$b='bbb';$c='ccc';
  $A=['a','b','c'];
  eval('$r='.KV($A));
  var_dump($r);
}

// running test1() now gives ['a'=>'aaa','b'=>'bbb','c'=>'ccc']
```

Comment: That's hell of a code that makes one's ones bleed for its naming, formatting, implementation and purpose. I wish you could have provided more context for your question so we would be able to suggest a sensible solution.

Answer (score -2):

You can [pass the array by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to be able to update within the function’s scope.

```
function KV(&$A, $t) {
    foreach ($A as $k => $v) {
        $A[$k] = $t[$v];
    }
}

function test1() {
    $t = [
        "a" => 'aaa',
        "b" => 'bbb',
        "c" => 'ccc',
    ];

    $A = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    KV($A, $t);
    var_dump($A);
}
```

Comment: The answer you provided doesn't appear to answer the question posed.